# Flutter, sending nesting FormData to server via Dio/http

Tags: spring, flutter, http, dart, dio

I want to post data to the postgres server. I need send info from the registration form along with some pictures. So I need to use multipart/form-data. The thing is my registration form is quite complicated and has couple of nested objects(below I will paste part of it so you can see what I am talking about).

And here I am after two days of research and trying different options I can't get it to work. Neither with http or Dio package, it seems like in Dio package FormData.fromMap() is formatiing it incorectly...

Is there any way to get it to work or I have ask someone from backend to separate registration form and pictures for two different request and send it as json...

Here is part of my form:

```
FormData.fromMap({
      "questionnaire": {
        "horse": {"name": "Abisynia", "breed": "demo", "sex": "male"},
        "owner": {
          "personal_data": "John Doe",
          "email": "asasdasss@gmail.com",
          "phone_number": "3556234432"
        },
        "breakfast": {"name": "morning", "manufacturer": "Adasa", "amount": 1},
        "dinner": {"name": "noon", "manufacturer": "Aasd", "amount": 2},
        "supper": {"name": "evening", "manufacturer": "ASds", "amount": 3}
      }
    })
```

Here are the logs from the server of what is being sent when I am posting(and it works!) with Postman:

[image: Postman logs]

And here are the logs when I try to post through my app:

[image: Logs from the app]

I will be gratefull for any ideas...

Comment: Hey have you found a fix for this? I've been stuck on the same issue for a while

Comment: I'm stuck at this for long. Can you please advise?

Answer (score 1):

For sending JSON data with `FormData`, you will need to send it as a `MultipartFile` and specify the content type to "application/json".

Like this:

```
final data = FormData.fromMap({
    "file": await MultipartFile.fromFile(
      path,
      filename: name,
    ),
    "jsonData": MultipartFile.fromString(
      jsonEncode({"name": "user_name"}),
      contentType: MediaType.parse('application/json'),
    ),
  },
);
```

Comment: This answer is very useful for me.
If one of the FormData field has nested JSON object then we can send like this!
`MultipartFile.fromString(jsonEncode({//jsonObject}))`

Comment: This `MultipartFile.fromString()` isn't even clear in the documentation. but you found it. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Encode the nested jsons before passing it to FormData. It will work. For example:

```
String horseJson = json.encode({"name": "Abisynia", "breed": "demo", "sex": "male"});
String ownerJson = json.encode({
          "personal_data": "John Doe",
          "email": "asasdasss@gmail.com",
          "phone_number": "3556234432"
        });
String breakfastJson = json.encode({"name": "morning", "manufacturer": "Adasa", "amount": 1});
String dinnerJson = json.encode({"name": "noon", "manufacturer": "Aasd", "amount": 2});
String supperJson = json.encode({"name": "evening", "manufacturer": "ASds", "amount": 3});
String questiinnaireJson = json.encode({
        "horse": horseJson,
        "owner": ownerJson,
        "breakfast": breakfastJson,
        "dinner": dinnerJson,
        "supper": supperJson
      });
FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
      "questionnaire": questiinnaireJson
    });
var response = await dio.post(url, data: formData, options: Options(headers:_headers));
```

Answer (score 0):

After hours of search I solved it.

If you want to post single nested Map lets say:

**Wrong:**

```
FormData.fromMap({

 parent_key: { child_key: child_value }

})
```

You need to convert it to:

**Correct**

```
FormData.fromMap({

 parent_key.child_key: child_value

})
```

And if you wanted to post list of maps lets say:

**Wrong:**

```
FormData.fromMap({

 parent_key: [

   { child_key: child_value },
   { child_key: child_value_02 }
]

})
```

You need to convert it to:

**Correct**

```
FormData.fromMap({

 parent_key[0]child_key: child_value
 parent_key[1]child_key: child_value_02

})
```